# Install GLPK on Google Colab for python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, pyomo, glpk

I want to use Pyomo in Google Colab.

I did this:

```
pip install pyomo #works 100%
pip install glpk  #error
```

the error is:

ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
  Running setup.py clean for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually we recommend installing glpk using conda. I'm not sure if Google Colab has conda installed but if so the command would be:

```
conda install -c conda-forge glpk
```

Also, I recommend taking a look at Chapter 1 of the Pyomo cookbooks [here](https://jckantor.github.io/ND-Pyomo-Cookbook/) which describe how to set up solvers to use with Pyomo and include notebooks that can be run in Google Colab.

Comment: Nice. Without conda it would be !apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils. Got it on the link that you posted. Ty

Answer (score 3):

Need to use both apt and pip to install it.

```
!pip install pyomo
!apt install glpk-utils
!pip install glpk
```